# What resources are best for staying current about information security?

Tags: untagged

What types of sites do you visit, on a regular basis, to stay current on information security issues? Some examples from my list include:

- http://isc.sans.org/
- http://www.kaspersky.com/viruswatch3
- http://www.schneier.com/blog/
- http://blog.fireeye.com/research/

As well as following the security heavyweights on twitter.

I'm curious to hear what resources you recommend for daily monitoring. Anything specific to particular operating systems or other software. Are mailing lists still considered valuable.

My goal would be to trim the cruft of all the things I'm currently subscribed to and focus on the essentials.

Comment: Fair enough. There really aren't many answers in that thread. I was hoping to create a more definitive list.

Answer (score 3):

I find that a lot of the mailing lists at [seclists.org](http://seclists.org/) have a lot of good information on security news, software vulnerabilities, and general security questions.

**EDIT:**You may also want to check out [this](http://pauldotcom.com/PaulsFeeds.opml) .opml file.  It's a list of blogs and RSS feeds that Paul Asadoorian of [PaulDotCom](http://pauldotcom.com) fame subscribes to.  There quite a few feeds in there ranging on all sorts of topics from hacking to information security.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites mentioned as well as 'magazines' such as [phrack](http://www.phrack.com/) and [2600](http://www.2600.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I subscribe via RSS to the following..

- http://www.net-security.org/
- http://www.governmentsecurity.org/
- http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specific security fora, a broader view of risks is well worth considering. For example:

- [ACM Risks Digest](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/risks)
- [Bruce Schneier's blog, newsletter](http://www.schneier.com) and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one has mentioned it, but the [Security Bloggers Network](http://www.securitybloggers.net/) is a feed with all the top security guys and companies.

Answer (score 0):

http://security.didici.cc/ is all I use nowadays. It's a news aggregator which includes many high quality news sources, as well as podcasts, videos, events, CVEs, Tweets, as well as stackexchange posts.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the site.