# Where do you go for security news?

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Security Resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/34523/security-resources)

Is there anywhere you go for security information or bullietins?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/34523/security-resources

Answer (score 2):

http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the balance of news you want, but http://www.theregister.co.uk provides a good range of technical news, incuding significant security news.

Answer (score 1):

SANS is sometimes of use http://isc.sans.org/

As are CERT's mailing lists: www.us-cert.gov/cas/signup.html

I guess it depends what it is you're interested in, security is a big topic

Answer (score 1):

I use [SANS](http://sans.org/) for much of my security [news](http://www.sans.org/free_resources.php).  They cover most platforms with a weekly @Risk email I like to scan for new exploits and vulnerabilities.

There are also sights more specific for the platforms your are running.  Like [eEye](http://eeye.com) who have a webcast which covers the monthly (second Tuesday of the month) Microsoft patch releases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure people will come up with a plethora of great news sites, so I'll recommend mailing lists. There's the (totally unmoderated) **Full Disclosure** mailing list that's a great resource if you really want unfiltered news about exploits/vulnerabilities and such (warning: there are also a lot of BS postings). The **DailyDave** mailing list is moderated and has a lot of the same sort of thing. I think **NTBugTraq** is still around too.

Hope some of that is useful.